# How to expand DataFrame rows based on a column's value?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a DataFrame like this:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Column 1': ['a', 'a', 'b', 'c'],
                  'Column 2': [2, 2, 3, 4],
                  'Column 3': [100, 110, 120, 130]}
                  )

>
  Column 1  Column 2  Column 3
0        a         2       100
1        a         2       110
2        b         3       120
3        c         4       130
```

and I need a new DF like this:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Column 1': ['a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'b', 'b', 'b', 'c', 'c', 'c', 'c'],
                  'New Column': ['a1', 'a2', 'a3', 'a4', 'b1', 'b2', 'b3', 'c1', 'c2', 'c3', 'c4'],
                  'Column 3': [100, 100, 110, 110, 120, 120, 120, 130, 130, 130, 130]}
                  )

   Column 1 New Column  Column 3
0         a         a1       100
1         a         a2       100
2         a         a3       110
3         a         a4       110
4         b         b1       120
5         b         b2       120
6         b         b3       120
7         c         c1       130
8         c         c2       130
9         c         c3       130
10        c         c4       130
```

I did it with 2 loops using itterrows and grouping by the "key" Column 1-Column 3, but it takes a long time to run and probably isn't the best solution, so I was wondering if there's a better way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`index.repeat`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Index.repeat.html) + [`loc`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html) to scale up the DataFrame based on the numbers in `Column 2` then [`reset_index`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reset_index.html) to convert to unique range index. Then [`insert`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.insert.html) the `New Column` into the `df` using [`groupby cumcount`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.cumcount.html):

```
# Scale up the DataFrame
df = df.loc[df.index.repeat(df.pop('Column 2'))].reset_index(drop=True)
# Insert new column in the correct place
df.insert(
    1, 'New Column',
    # Create New Column based on new Column 1 Values
    df['Column 1'] + df.groupby('Column 1').cumcount().add(1).astype(str)
)
```

`df`:

```
   Column 1 New Column  Column 3
0         a         a1       100
1         a         a2       100
2         a         a3       110
3         a         a4       110
4         b         b1       120
5         b         b2       120
6         b         b3       120
7         c         c1       130
8         c         c2       130
9         c         c3       130
10        c         c4       130
```

Comment: kindly check your output ~

Comment: Much better now ~ happy coding ~ :-)